# Can I command the troopers attached to me in Halo Reach?

Tags: halo-reach

In the ONI Sword Base level, I'm told certain troopers will follow me around. I see there names next to the radar. This feature of the game has be a bit confused... Is there anyway for me to herd these troopers in the right direction? Can I give them commands? Will they only act autonomously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can not command your troopers. The most interaction you have with them is seeing their health on the bottom left of your screen, their names, and they will generally follow you around into combat. However if you flee combat, the troopers will not follow and continue fighting.

Answer (score 1):

They just act autonomously.

Answer (score 1):

No, they just follow you and provide support.